# Service injection not working in Angular Typescript Filter

Tags: angularjs, typescript

i am trying to access the app Constant inside a filter 
But its failing to get the service inside the filter. How can i access a service in angular typescript Filter ?

module App.Filter {

```
  import Shared = Core.Shared;


  export class MilestoneStatusFilter123 {
    static $inject = ['appConstant'];
    constructor(public appConstant: Shared.AppConstants) {
    }
    public static factory(): Function {
      return (input: number) => {
        switch (input) {
          case 1:
            return this.appConstant.someVal;
          case 2:
            return "n";
          case 3:
            return "n";
          case 4:
            return "n";
        }
      }
    }  
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a static context (here the `factory()`), `this` is not what you expect. Moreover you are probably registering the filter using `MilestoneStatusFilter123.factory()`. Angular will never construct this class, will just call the static method. No chance of injecting the dependencies.

Do the following instead (here the `factory` is a dependency injection array, suitable for Angular and the filter function gets the dependency from the closure):

```
import Shared = Core.Shared;

export class MilestoneStatusFilter123 {
    public static factory: ['appConstant', (appConstant: Shared.AppConstants): Function => {
        return (input: number) => {
            switch (input) {
                case 1:
                    return this.appConstant.someVal;
                case 2:
                    return "n";
                case 3:
                    return "n";
                case 4:
                    return "n";
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Register it as (note: no parentheses after `.factory`):

```
angular.module(...).filter('...', MilestoneStatusFilter123.factory);
```